# Docker RUN statement (modifying a file) not executed

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I am experiencing strange behavior when executing a Dockerfile (in https://github.com/Krijger/es-nagios-docker). Basically, I add a file to append its contents to a file in the image

```
ADD es-command /tmp/
RUN cat tmp/es-command >> /opt/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg
```

The problem is that, while */tmp/es-command* is present in the resulting image, the *commands.cfg* file was not changed.

As a prelude to the accepted answer: my Dockerfile extends *cpuguy83/nagios*, which defines */opt/nagios/etc* as a volume.

Comment: What is the base image? i.e. what is your FROM statement? This worked for me with `FROM ubuntu:14.04`

Comment: it shall work, it has problem in other place, this is basic feature. please show the complete Dockerfile, or put into github

Comment: @andy please see the edit with more info (it is now available in github)

Comment: answered below, please clean up your question, remove useless information, key is your base image is `cpuguy83/nagios`. If you want to solve this problem. like how to update config in readonly filesystem, please open another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to the see sample code, which find the route cause.

Your docker image comes from `cpuguy83/nagios`, from this image https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-nagios/blob/master/Dockerfile

You can see `/opt/nagios/etc` directory is set as **VOLUME**

```
 VOLUME ["/opt/nagios/var", "/opt/nagios/etc", "/opt/nagios/libexec", "/var/log/apache2", "/usr/share/snmp/mibs"]
```

Then you can notice that [docker volume](http://docs.docker.io/use/working_with_volumes/) can't be changed at the next commit by your new build.

And this is the reason you can see your changes when you enter into the container and lost it when exits.

Comment: Thank you!!! I completely missed that and was exploring completely other directions. Good lesson.

Comment: Yes , this is an issue with how Docker handled volumes during the build phase (that is, that it's exactly the same as the non-build phase).  If I were you I would just clone my repo and add the file in before the volume.  I suppose I could set it up to not make a volume on etc for those who want to be able to inherit from it.

Comment: Truly though, I place custom config files during orchestration using volumes-from, not in the image.  I'll post this solution as soon as I get to a computer

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I use it:

```
ls ./
    configure.sh
    commands.cfg

cat configure.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    script_path=$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )
    cp ${script_path}/commands.cfg /opt/nagios/etc/objects/



docker run -d --name nagios cpuguy83/nagios
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/tmp --volumes-from nagios --entrypoint /tmp/configure.sh cpuguy83/nagios
```